# Add Dynamic Sidebar to Exisiting WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the SoulVision WordPress theme, I'm trying to add a bottom sidebar to the already existing Top, Left and Right sidebars, however, I can't get it to successfully work. Any help would be appreciated. My coding is below.

style.css

```
/*-- Sidebar settings --*/
#sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
    color:#DEDABF;
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
}
#sidebar a:hover {
    color: #C58556;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar h2 {
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid #8E6140;
    margin:0;
    padding:3px 0 6px 8px;
    background: url(images/h2-bg.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}
#sidebar ul li strong {
    color:#FC0;
}
#sidebar-top {
    width:390px;
    padding:5px;
}
.sidebar-top-box {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-left: 1px solid #8E6140;
}
.box-padding {
    padding:7px;
}
.sidebar-top-box p {
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
#sidebar-top h2 {
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#CFA97E;
}
#sidebar-top .textwidget {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:7px;
    border-right: 1px solid #A1674F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A1674F;
    border-left: 1px solid #A1674F;
}
#sidebar-top ul ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px 7px 7px 12px;
    border-right: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-left: 1px solid #8E6140;
}
#sidebar-top ul ul li {
    padding-left:10px;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-image:url(images/lidot.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
#sidebar-top ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#sidebar-top .box-ads a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#sidebar-left {
    float:left;
    width:215px;
    padding:0 10px 0 5px;
}
#sidebar #sidebar-left h2, #sidebar #sidebar-right h2 {
    margin:15px 0 10px;
    color: #CFA97E;
}
#sidebar-right {
    float:right;
    width:153px;
    padding:0 5px 0 10px;
}
#sidebar-left ul ul, #sidebar-right ul ul {
    padding-left:5px;
}
html, #sidebar ul, #sidebar-wrap ul, .rel-posts ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#sidebar-right li, #sidebar-left li {
    background:url(images/lidot.gif) no-repeat left top;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 5px 8px;
}
#sidebar-left  .children, #sidebar-right  .children {
    padding-top: 8px;
}
#sidebar-left  ul.children  li, #sidebar-right  ul.children  li {
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
#sidebar   h2  a.rsswidget {
    color: #CFA97E;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar .rsswidget img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 7px;
}
/*-- Bottom Sidebar --*/
#sidebar-bottom {
    width:390px;
    padding:5px;
}
.sidebar-bottom-box {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-left: 1px solid #8E6140;
}
.box-padding {
    padding:7px;
}
.sidebar-bottom-box p {
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}
#sidebar-bottom h2 {
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#CFA97E;
}
#sidebar-bottom .textwidget {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:7px;
    border-right: 1px solid #A1674F;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A1674F;
    border-left: 1px solid #A1674F;
}
#sidebar-bottom ul ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px 7px 7px 12px;
    border-right: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8E6140;
    border-left: 1px solid #8E6140;
}
#sidebar-bottom ul ul li {
    padding-left:10px;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-image:url(images/lidot.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left top;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
#sidebar-bottom ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#sidebar-bottom .box-ads a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

sidebar.php

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="sidebar-top">
    <ul id="top-sidebarwidgets">
      <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_top') ) : else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div id="sidebar-left">
    <ul id="l_sidebarwidgets">
      <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_left') ) : else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-right">
    <ul id="r_sidebarwidgets">
      <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_right') ) : else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-bottom">
    <ul id="bottom-sidebarwidgets">
      <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_bottom') ) : else : ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following code, my sidebars display like this - i.imgur.com/omMfa.png

But if I change the sidebar.php code to this

```
<div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar-top">
        <ul id="top-sidebarwidgets">
          <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_top') ) : else : ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div id="sidebar-bottom">
        <ul id="bottom-sidebarwidgets">
          <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_bottom') ) : else : ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar-left">
        <ul id="l_sidebarwidgets">
          <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_left') ) : else : ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="sidebar-right">
        <ul id="r_sidebarwidgets">
          <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar_right') ) : else : ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then the sidebar will display like this - i.imgur.com/UATs6.png

So, it appears to me that there's an issue when adding it below the existing ones. Any help would be wonderful. The site can be previewed live at http://www.itsdaniel0.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some issues with out of place div and ul tags that will cause layout problems. See
[[Invalid]Markup Validation of   itsdaniel0.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.itsdaniel0.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: There are a few errors on my site (main FB and Speak/Voice search). However, the Q was answered here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12511/add-dynamic-sidebar-to-exisiting-wordpress-theme.

I needed to add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`